# List View HTML Static vs Dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, listview, html-lists

I'm trying to dynamically create HTML lists using some random JSON data
The code is -

```
 <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
     <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Lists</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h2>AJAX List View</h2>
      <div id='list'></div>
     </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var str;
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               str = xmlhttp.responseText;
               str = JSON.parse(str);
               var q = "";
               for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
                q += "<div data-role='collapsible' data-inset='false'><h4>" + str[i].title + "</h4>";
                q += "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'><li>Details: " + str[i].duration + "</li><li>Price: " + str[i].price + "</li></ul>";
                q += "</div>";
               }
               document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = q;
           }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://phonegappro.esy.es/test/json.php", true);
          xmlhttp.send();    
       </script>
 </div>
```

When I run this code it views something like this - 
[image]

But when I try to do the above in a static manner by writing every UL & OL it runs as I need.

[image]

Header Libs -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: run it with the JSON and post the HTML that is being outputted please.

Comment: here is the HTML being outputted - http://pastebin.com/788PMLsH

Comment: What library are you using to make the `data-role="collapsible"` items collapsible? Apparently it runs before your script has injected the HTML. If you can find which function is called onload, call the same function after you're done injecting the HTML.

Comment: I think it may just be a matter of moving where you run the JSON parse script or checking if there is just a div out of place/missing when you run it?

Comment: I tried it moving the JSOn code to head, end of body everywhere but it produces the same output & div elements are in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did the `data-role="collapsible" & data-role="listview"` is attribute for jQueryMobile objects?

if yes, after ajax loaded successfully, you need to re-draw them to make sure they are compiled with right appearances.

Refers from [jQueryMobile api documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/), you can draw the collapsible using this:

```
$( ".selector" ).collapsible();
```

and this is for [listview](https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/) drawing init:

```
$( "#mylist" ).listview();
```

For your script, you need add those two initializer just like this:

```
var str;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        str = xmlhttp.responseText;
        str = JSON.parse(str);
        var q = "";
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            q += "<div data-role='collapsible' data-inset='false'><h4>" + str[i].title + "</h4>";
            q += "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'><li>Details: " + str[i].duration + "</li><li>Price: " + str[i].price + "</li></ul>";
            q += "</div>";
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = q;
    }

    $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible();
    $('ul[data-role="listview"]').listview();
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://phonegappro.esy.es/test/json.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Pardon me for my bad english :)

Comment: glad to help you :)